# Overloading operator using templates c++

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I am making a matrix library and I would like to be able to do something like

```
Matrix<double> = Matrix<int> + Matrix<double>
```

is this possible?

Here is what I have now:

```
template<typename T>
Matrix<T>& Matrix<T>::operator+(const Matrix& rhs) {
  if(w != rhs.w || h != rhs.h) {
    printf("\e[31m[ERROR] Arithmetic Error: attempted to add %dx%d matrix to %dx%d matrix\e[0m\n", w, h, rhs.w, rhs.h);
  }
  else {
    for(uint32_t i = 0;i < size;++i) {
      m[i] += rhs.m[i];
    }
  }
  return *this;
}
```

Comment: `operator+` which mutate its operands is strange, it looks more as `operator +=` than `operator+`.

Answer (score 2):

You can make `operator+` template then it could accept other instantiations of `Matrix`.

E.g.

```
template<typename T>
template<typename X>
Matrix<T>& Matrix<T>::operator+(const Matrix<X>& rhs) {
  if(w != rhs.w || h != rhs.h) {
    printf("\e[31m[ERROR] Arithmetic Error: attempted to add %dx%d matrix to %dx%d matrix\e[0m\n", w, h, rhs.w, rhs.h);
  }
  else {
    for(uint32_t i = 0;i < size;++i) {
      m[i] += rhs.m[i];
    }
  }
  return *this;
}
```

Note that for your current implementation, you have to confirm that the current instantiation is allowed to access members of other instantiations like `rhs.w`. Different instantiations are considered as different types.

Answer (score 0):

template free function might solve your issue, something like:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
auto operator+(const Matrix<T1>& lhs, const Matrix<T2>& rhs)
{
    if (lhs.w != rhs.w || lhs.h != rhs.h) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Incompatible size");
    }
    using T = decltype(std::declval<T1>() + std::declval<T2>());
    Matrix<T> res(lhs.w, lhs.h);

    for (uint32_t i = 0; i != res.size; ++i) {
      res.m[i] = lhs.m[i] + rhs.m[i];
    }
    return res;
}
```